# Why does Sublime Text 3 require elevation to save?

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3

I switched over to Ubuntu 16 LTS and I thought everything was going well, until I imported a project from my old Windows 10 dev system. Now I have to elevate permissions every time I create a file or try to save. Absolutely ridiculous! Here's the request:

`Authentication is needed to run '/bin/cp' as the super user`

I checked permissions, and as far as I know, they are good. Same group. I am an admin. And when I create/modify files via terminal, I don't require similar elevation. But when I create them through Sublime Text 3, elevation required.

I read about disabling Atomic Save, but that is set by default, so I have no idea what the heck is going on.  Ubuntu is not my OS (yet).

This whole bloody experience is exhausting! At any rate, does anybody know how to fix this? It appears to be permission related and for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

TIA.

WR!

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -l /bin/cp`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 151024 Mar  2  2017 /bin/cp*  ......  seriously???  ONLY root can run binaries??  how the heck are users supposed to do anything on this system??  what stymies me: I AM A MEMBER OF ROOT GROUP!!! so when i run ST3, why isn't it using those permissions???